# Sending multiple messages with DataOutputStream

Tags: c#, android, tcpclient, networkstream, dataoutputstream

I'm trying to send 3 messages from an Android tcp client to a C# Server. It works properly in another C# client, but it doesn't in the Android client.
I send 3 messages but the server gets the first message correctly but then the second and the third joined like they were just one message

Server code:

```
NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
byte[] buffer = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];
int data = stream.Read(buffer, 0, client.ReceiveBufferSize);
string message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, data);
int one = Int32.Parse(message);
buffer = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];
data = stream.Read(buffer, 0, client.ReceiveBufferSize);
message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, data);
int two = Int32.Parse(message);
buffer = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];
data = stream.Read(buffer, 0, client.ReceiveBufferSize);
message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, data);
int three = Int32.Parse(message);
```

the Android client is:

```
EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText01);
String one = "56";
String two = "300";
String three = "4";
DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
out.writeBytes(one);
out.flush();
out.writeBytes(two);
out.flush();
out.writeBytes(three);
out.flush();
```

The server gets: `one = 56 two = 3004`

Instead of: `one = 56 two = 300 three = 4`

Comment: The server could as well have received once 563004. It is you who should provide message separating characters.  Very normal all.

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Comment: `out.writeBytes(one + "\n" );` And so on. See if you can let the server read lines.